# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1' in virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

I tried to install scrapy in a virtual env on OSX and encountered:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy",
>   line 7, in 
>       from scrapy.cmdline import execute   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 9, in
>   
>       from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 7, in
>   
>       from twisted.internet import reactor, defer   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/reactor.py", line
>   38, in 
>       from twisted.internet import default   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line
>   56, in 
>       install = _getInstallFunction(platform)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line
>   50, in _getInstallFunction
>       from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from twisted.internet import posixbase   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 28,
>   in 
>       from twisted.internet._newtls import (   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line
>   21, in 
>       from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 63,
>   in 
>       from twisted.internet._sslverify import _setAcceptableProtocols   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py",
>   line 38, in 
>       TLSVersion.TLSv1_1: SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1, **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'**

---

I tried these:

1. `pip install Twisted==16.4.1`
2. `pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSl`

But still get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'`

My python version is 2.7.10

Tried these and all got "Requirement already up-to-date: ...":

```
pip install --upgrade scrapy
pip install --upgrade twisted
pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
```

Hope to work it out.... Thanks!

Comment: What do you get by issuing `$ brew list | grep openssl`?

Comment: Hi @hoefling, I got `openssl`